# Tensor product and linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, tensors

I am studying tensor products and the following question came up to me, and dummit and foote does not address an answer to this. Is the following statement true?

Let us consider $M^{\otimes 3}$, where $R$ is a commutative ring and $M$ is a module over $R$. Let $x,y,z \in M$. If $x \otimes y \otimes z=0$ then $x=ry+r'z$ for some $r,r' \in R$.

Would it change if we assume $M$ to be free?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

False. In $({\Bbb Z}_9)^{\otimes 3}$ over $\Bbb Z$ we have $x \otimes 3 \otimes 3 = 0$ for all $x$, but since $\langle 3\rangle = \{0,3,6\}$, any $x\not\in \langle 3\rangle$ gives a counter-example.

---

Suppose $M$ is free with basis $\{e_i\}_{i\in I}$. Then $M^{\otimes 3}$ is also free with basis $\{e_i\otimes e_j \otimes e_k\}_{(i,j,k)\in I^3}$. Write $x = \sum_{i\in I} x_i e_i$, and similarly for $y$ and $z$ (finite sums). Assume $y,z\neq 0$. Then $$0 = x \otimes y \otimes z = \sum_{i,j,k\in I} x_i y_j z_k e_i \otimes e_j \otimes e_k,$$and so $x_iy_jz_k = 0$ for all choices of $i,j$ and $k$. There are $j_0,k_0\in I$ such that $y_{j_0},z_{k_0}\neq 0$. Then if $R$ is a domain, $x_iy_{j_0}z_{k_0}=0$ gives $x_i=0$. But since $i$ was arbitrary, $x=0$.

This clearly adapts to $M^{\otimes n}$, in the same setting. Only more boring to write with all indices and such.

Comment: Same seems to work in $(\Bbb Z_{n^2})^{\otimes 3}$ looking at $x\otimes n \otimes n $ and picking a suitable $x$, by the way.

Comment: How about if we suppose $M$ to be free? Would that help?

Comment: You mean, if the statement if true if $M$ is free? Then I'd have to think more.

Comment: Hell, just take $ x \otimes 0 \otimes 0 = 0$ with $x \neq 0$. I should have seen that sooner.

Comment: @Ale I managed to prove that if $M$ is free and $R$ is a domain, if $y,z\neq 0$, then $x=0$. I'm yet to find a counter-example in case $R$ is not a domain, but if you'll accept this result as the answer I can write it down when I'm not on mobile...

Comment: @Ale Proof of claim added!

Comment: There also this [extra result here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/index.php?page=tag&tag=04VX).